# Want all %n groups that aren't inside backticks or quotes

Tags: java, regex

I want to match out all substrings of the form %n, where n is a number along with the first word before a space:

e.g.

```
"foo %1     %2   %3"
```

Would return `foo %1 %2 %3`

However, the string may also have quotes or backticks, in the following I would not want %4 returned.

```
"foo %1 %2    `bar %4` %3" <= only return foo %1 %2 %3
"foo %1 %2 'bar %4 ' %3" <= only return foo %1 %2 %3 as %4 is between ''
"foo %2 `bar  %1 quax`" <= only returns foo %2 as %1 is between ``
"foo %a %1" <= only returns foo %1
```

The percentage should only be returned if its followed by one or more digits.

What I have so far

```
^(\w+)\s+(%\d+\s*)*
```

I don't know how to make it treat the `(%\d+\s*) bit as it's own thing and do it repeatedly.

Java regex.

Thanks,

Comment: Use a negative lookbehind to prohibit backtick before the match.

Comment: Read https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html to learn how to use lookbehind and lookahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with `\G` in Java to get all your matches:

```sh
(?:^(?=.*%\d+)(\w+)|(?<!\A)\G)(?:\h+(?:`[^`]*`|'[^']*'|%\D\S*))*\h+(%\d+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PYgsYF/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `^`: Start
  - `(?=.*%\d+)`: Lookahead to make sure we have a `%<digit>` somewhere
  - `(\w+)`: Match and capture starting word in group #1
  - `|`: OR
  - `(?<!\A)\G`: `\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match. By placing `(?<!\A)` we ensure `\G` is not matched at the start
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `(?:\h+(?:'[^']*'|%\D\S*))*`: Match and consume any text that is `'...'` or backtick quoted string or a `%<non-digit`
- `\h+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
- `(%\d+)`: Match and capture `%<digits>` in group #2

Comment: Thanks! ANyway to make it match `foo :a %1` the %1 here? Or for example `foo %1 :b %2` would match %1 and %2?

Comment: If you have `:b` strings also then use this: https://regex101.com/r/PYgsYF/2

Answer (score 2):

Think of it the other way around. Instead of retrieving the parts that are *not* quoted, delete the quoted parts. After that, you may apply your regex to retrieve individual groups and filter out things like `%a` and spaces.

```
String mayContainQuotes = ...;
String noQuotes = mayContainQuotes.replaceAll("`.*?`|'.*?'", " ");
Pattern.compile("^(\\w+)\\s+(%\\d+\\s*)*").matcher(noQuotes);
```